# printing the value of concatenated string and integer

Tags: python

```
a_1 = 1234
a_2 = 1235
a_3= 1236
a_4= 12345

for i in range(1,count):
    print("a_"+str(i))
```

I want to print the value of the variable instead of string

Comment: dont do this. **use a container** like a list, or a dict

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want exactly what you say:

```
a_1 = 1234
a_2 = 1235
a_3= 1236
a_4= 12345

count=5

for i in range(1,count):
    print(vars()["a_"+str(i)])
```

Output:

```
1234
1235
1236
12345
```

If not, and you just wanted to print some values stored use lists, tuples etc.

eg.

```
a = [1234,1235,1236,12345]

count = len(a) #5
for i in range(0,count):
    print(a[i])
```

Output:

```
1234
1235
1236
12345
```

Or simply:

```
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
1234
1235
1236
12345
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), i.e.:

```
a_1 = 1234
a_2 = 1235
a_3= 1236
a_4= 12345

for i in range(1, 5):
    print(eval("a_"+str(i)))
```

---

```
1234
1235
1236
12345
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/1dcf87fd68)